# Is it possible to execute code after a program has crashed?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windows-10

I want to be able to dump information from the application when a crash occurs.  Is it possible to do something like assign a callback to be called when a program crashes?  The callback would dump data from the application.  The data dumped would be application specific that may be in the stack dump but in a easier format for non-programmers to read.

The operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: I think this is something you should ask from your operating system, not your program.

Comment: _"I want to be able to dump information from the application when a crash occurs"_ That's usually already done by the operating system (look for _stack trace dump_)

Comment: There are tools that do this. So it must be possible, but how very much depends on your operating system

Comment: Is your program crashing from an unhandled exception?  If so you can write your own custom [`terminate_handler`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler)

Comment: What is the operating system, that you are targetting? Windows has SEH, but am not sure about Linux.

Comment: That's what a "core dump" (Unix) and "MiniDump/FullDump" (Windows) is for.

Comment: The concept of a crash is something that exists outside the scope of the language. Unless you are specifically asking about handling `std::abort` or `std::terminate` or other language specified process ending functions. But if you are asking about handling unexpected crashes then it's a problem you have to solve outside of the scope of c++. It entirely depends on how and on what you run your code.

Comment: _@zooropa_ For Windows 10 you should compile your project in debug mode, enable stack dump, and you'll get one if the program _"crashes"_. If you have this, you can load it in your debugger, and inspect your programs state at the time the _crash"_ occurred.

Comment: @JesperJuhl core dump is hardly "easier format for non-programmers to read" though. (Unless by non-programmer, OP means machine).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/werapi/nf-werapi-werregistermemoryblock let's you tag memory to be included in the crash dump.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to execute code after a program has crashed?

Typically, depending on the operating system, the process will receive a signal from the OS prior to their termination. The signal handler (if one has been registered and the signal is not masked) has a chance to execute code before the process is terminated.

After termination, the process doesn't exist, cannot execute code, and its memory is no longer accessible.

The functions that may safely be used in a signal handler are limited. The C++ standard guarantees safety of following functions (may be non-exhaustive in case I've missed some):

```
_Exit
abort
forward
initializer_list functions
memcpy
memmove
move
move_if_noexcept
numeric_limits members
quick_exit
signal
type traits
plain lock-free atomic operations
```

Note that none of the functions guaranteed by the standard can do output. Your operating system may allow other functions as well, and should have documentation that lists them. POSIX standard guarantees safety of `open` and `write` functions, which can be used for output.

---

The above assumes that the source of the crash is outside the program (e.g. user requests termination from OS, or your process accesses invalid memory and OS reacts to that). If the source of the crash is from inside the program, in particular if `std::terminate` is called by you or the standard library, then you can instead register a `std::terminate_handler`, which is not so limited as a signal handler is.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for Windows programs is to use the MiniDumpWriteDump function.  This page describes different alternatives for writing a minidump when a crash occurs in Windows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxtecharts/crash-dump-analysis

Comment: Link only answers aren't really good here (links may age out and land with a 404). At least cite what the docs say there.